# Render a collection with different classes one time in two

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a beginner using AngularJS.

I would like to render a collection in my HTML code, with a specific directive: one item at left, the following one at right, the third one at left etc...

```
<div ng-repeat="Model in Collection">

  <!-- The HTML i need for even iterations -->
  <div class="col-xs-2.col-sm-2.col-md-2.col-lg-2.col-xs-offset-2.col-sm-offset-2.col-md-offset-2.col-lg-offset-2">
    <img alt="Player" src="{{Model.avatar}}" popover-placement="left">
  </div>

  <!-- The HTML i need for odd iterations -->
  <div class="col-xs-2.col-sm-2.col-md-2.col-lg-2.col-xs-offset-8.col-sm-offset-8.col-md-offset-8.col-lg-offset-8">
    <img alt="Player" src="{{Model.avatar}}" popover-placement="right">
  </div>

</div>
```

What is the better way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of ng-class-odd and ng-class-even to declare the class of the divs.

```
<div ng-repeat="Model in Collection">

  <div ng-class-even="'col-xs-2.col-sm-2.col-md-2.col-lg-2.col-xs-offset-2.col-sm-offset-2.col-md-offset-2.col-lg-offset-2'" 
       ng-class-odd="'col-xs-2.col-sm-2.col-md-2.col-lg-2.col-xs-offset-8.col-sm-offset-8.col-md-offset-8.col-lg-offset-8'">
    <img alt="Player" src="{{Model.avatar}}" ng-class-even="'left'" ng-class-odd="'right'">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Take a look here for further documentation : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClassEven